# wifi firmware installation instruction procedure

Tags: wireless, drivers, broadcom

my devices  chip id is BCM4312 LP-PHY chip (PCI ID 14E4:4315),please give me the instruction to install firmware-b43-lpphy-installer.

Comment: https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=firmware-b43-lpphy-installer

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what are you trying to do.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer` should work after a reboot

Answer (score 0):

firmware-b43-lpphy-installer is obsolete in new Ubuntu versions.

For this adapter you can install wl driver.

```
 sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Comment: what should i do further,
DKMS: install completed.
update-initramfs is disabled since running on read-only media

Comment: Why is it running on read-only media? Did you boot from LiveCD or what?

Comment: According to the link you gave him above, `bcmwl-kernel-source` is incorrect.

Comment: @chili555 But it is correct for this chip. I made some edits to that post, but probably missed something. List of supported by wl chips changes.

Comment: @chili555 I made edits there.